# Right aligning atom in chemfig

Tags: horizontal-alignment, chemfig

I'm using `chemfig` (perhaps improperly) for relational algebra graphs. Here, for example, is a simple one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}

\newcommand{\select}{\sigma}
\newcommand{\project}{\pi}
\newcommand{\join}{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\Join}}}}}

\begin{document}
    \chemfig{R-[:30]\join(-[:90]\project_{CodR,NomeR})-[:330]
        \select_{Argomento='moto'}-[:270]A}
\end{document}
```

It results in:

[image: graph]

I'd like to make the atoms containing `\select` and `\project` "right-aligned", so that the bond would touch the sigma and the pi. I didn't find a solution in the chemfig documentation.

If what I want is not possible with `chemfig`, are there viable alternatives?

EDIT: Maybe there is a way by redefining `\printatom`? I found an example in the docs in which it shows how to change font, so maybe it's possible to make a custom box.

Comment: This could help you http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/nodes-and-shapes/

Comment: @Sigur Thanks, I was aware of tikz, but it seems much more complex than chemfig for these simple graphs. I think I'll fallback on tikz if there is no way with chemfig.

Comment: are you sure that you don't want `\`moto'` instead of `'moto'`?

Comment: @Sigur Oh right I missed that bit. I always forget that in text mode that happens. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple: add `|` after `\select`:

> The character “`|`” forces splitting of the atom when it is encountered.
>   Thus we can write `C|{(CH_3)_3}` to ensure that ChemFig separates just
>   two atoms here: “`C`” and “`{(CH_3)_3}`”.

Without `\select_{Argomento='moto'}` is considered one atom and the bond is centered. With `|` we have two atoms where the bond can go to. In this case `\select` is chosen. If it weren't the optional arguments of the bonds would allow to determine which atom the bond should go to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}

\newcommand{\select}{\sigma}
\newcommand{\project}{\pi}
\newcommand{\join}{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\Join}}}}}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  R-[:30]\join
  (-[:90]\project_{CodR,NomeR})
  -[:330]
  \select|_{Argomento='moto'}
  -[:270]A
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @rubik, this solution is much more simpler than mine and it is the right one!

Comment: The only advantage I see in my solution is the alignment of the structure. In my code the `\Join` is the center since the script text is not taking horizontal space. This could be good if using captions.

Comment: @Sigur probably depends on the overall layout where this figure is used :) What needs more fixing is the spacing in the subscripts (I am also not sure the two primes around `moto` are actually wanted) – but that wasn't the question, so…

Comment: yes. I recommended the OP to accept your solution. Also I did a comparison between them. Nice!

Comment: Ah, this is really nice. I encountered this in the documentation, but I didn't understand how it actually works and ended up discarding it. But why isn't the figure centered, even if I added `\centering`? If it's possible to center the figure I'll accept this answer!

Comment: @rubik your question didn't say anything about centering of objects in LaTeX so I didn't answer it. This actually sounds like a new question to me. (If you mean the differences to Sigur's solution – actually *his* diagram isn't centered – it just *looks* as if it were.)

Comment: Ok, you are right, that was an inaccuracy on my part, I didn't specify it, although I took it as granted as I used `\centering`.

Comment: @rubik you probably need to post a new question explaining your problems: I have no problems whatsoever with `\begin{center} \chemfig{...} \end{center}` or `{\centering\chemfig{...}\par}` – both works just fine for me (Im still wondering if your actual question is about the different bounding boxes of mine and Sigur's solution?)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't want to create confusion. Your solution works and I'll keep it. If in the future I'll want to change the horizontal aligment I'll surely open a new question. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}

\newcommand{\select}{\sigma}
\newcommand{\project}{\pi}
\newcommand{\join}{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\Join}}}}}

\begin{document}
    \chemfig{R-[:30]\join(-[:90]\project_{\rlap{\scriptsize CodR,NomeR}})-[:330]
        \select_{\rlap{\scriptsize Argomento='moto'}}-[:270]A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** here is a comparison with the **right** solution given by @clemens. The difference will appears with we want to centre the chain.

My solution using `\rlap{}` makes the script 'invisible' with respect to horizontal alignment. This makes the `\Join` be the centre of the chain.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised it's so simple! Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Never heard of `\rlap` before thanks! One thing: this makes the subscript text normally sized, I had to get it back to a smaller size with `\scriptsize`.

Comment: @rubik, well observed. I edited the post to insert `\scriptsize`. As you could imagine, there is also the `\llap{}`.